# JS: When do dynamically inserted scripts get executed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to do an AJAX call at the top of the head and once it is done, insert a script with its content depending on the result of the ajax call. Something like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://mypage.com/');
  request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      if (result.foo === 'bar') {
        insertScript('bar');
      } else {
        insertScript('not bar');
      }
    }
  };
  request.send();
}
```

Insert Script code:

```
function insertScript (msg) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  var content = "console.log('" + msg + "');";
  var inlineScript = document.createTextNode(content);
  script.appendChild(inlineScript);
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

So now I am wondering: **When does the script gets executed?** I want it to execute as fast as possible. It gets attached to the head. What if the dom-parser already reached the body? Will it stop and execute the new script in the head first? Will it render everything and then execute the script?

Comment: The body will already have been reached and parsed  since `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous.

Comment: Afaik it will execute during the `head.appendChild` call. As you are using the DOM, not emitting html with `document.write`, it doesn't matter what the current state of the parser is.

Comment: Good to know! So it actually also doesn't matter where I place the script, wether I insert into the head or body?

Answer (score 1):

It will execute the script immediately. But, for a safe side you can inject a self executable function, like below:-

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
var content = "(function selfCallableFunction(){console.log('" + msg + "');})()";
var inlineScript = document.createTextNode(content);
script.appendChild(inlineScript);
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: What is safer with self executable function? Preventing variable overriding?

Comment: Self execution method is always a better approach. It creates a closure scope and prevents variable name clashing.